# Get the coordinates of the point on a line which has been modified in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I have a Linestring feature as my route on the openlayers map.
I use Modify class to make changes on the route. After every time that I modify this line I need to get the coordinates of the point which has been moved. (Ideally coordinates of the point before and after the modification.)

why do I need it: I need to add waypoints to my route. so after every modification I need to store the coordinates of the modified points of the line as my waypoints and send them to my routing API.

I use openlayers version 6.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a copy of the coordinates at the `modifystart` event, take another at the `modifyend` event.  Then find the coordinate which has been added, removed or changed:

```
   let oldCoordinates;
    modify.on('modifystart', (e) => {
      oldCoordinates = e.features
        .item(0)
        .getGeometry()
        .clone()
        .getCoordinates();
    });
    modify.on('modifyend', (e) => {
      const newCoordinates = e.features
        .item(0)
        .getGeometry()
        .clone()
        .getCoordinates();
      if (newCoordinates.length < oldCoordinates.length) {
        const removed = oldCoordinates.find(
          (coordinate, index) =>
            coordinate[0] !== newCoordinates[index][0] &&
            coordinate[1] !== newCoordinates[index][1]
        );
        console.log('removed', removed);
      } else if (newCoordinates.length > oldCoordinates.length) {
        const added = newCoordinates.find(
          (coordinate, index) =>
            coordinate[0] !== oldCoordinates[index][0] &&
            coordinate[1] !== oldCoordinates[index][1]
        );
        console.log('added', added);
      } else {
        let changedFrom;
        const changedTo = newCoordinates.find((coordinate, index) => {
          changedFrom = oldCoordinates[index];
          return (
            coordinate[0] !== changedFrom[0] && coordinate[1] !== changedFrom[1]
          );
        });
        console.log('changed from', changedFrom, 'to', changedTo);
      }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/modify-route-2rm65d